# How can I align this equation well?

Tags: align

I try formulate some lambda expression in lambda calculus. It is similar to a code, but I have to use align environment because it contains math symbols. I wonder how I can formulate its structures better? The current one has a lot of unneeded spaces in between, although it captures some of what I want it to look like.

```
\begin{align*}
\text{cell} = & \text{rec} (& \lambda b.&\lambda c.  &\lambda m.&  \\
              &             & \text{if} &(\text{get?}&(m),      &  \\
              &             &           & \text{seq} &(\text{send}&(\text{contents}(m), c), & \text{ready}(b(c))), \\
              &             &           & \text{if}  &(\text{set?}&(m), & \\
              &             &           &            & \text{ready}&(b(\text{contents}(m))), & \\
              &             &           &            & \text{ready}&(b(c))))) 
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Here is what I want

[image]

Comment: Hi, may be You have image of what You wonna have as a result, it would be very nice

Comment: Thanks. Question updated.

Comment: Try replacing `{align*}` with `{alignat*}{3}` (I suppose you made the right calculation and have three alignment points).

Comment: Is it the last image an algorithm?

Comment: a lambda expression, using math symbol @Sebastiano

Comment: @Ben Thank you for your reply. I not know the lambda expression :-( Sorry.

Comment: If one of the answers given has solved your problem please also consider to [accept](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite what you want, but how about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
\text{cell} ={} & \text{rec} ( & & \lambda\mathrlap{ b.\lambda c. \lambda m.} \\
               & & & \text{if} &( & \mathrlap{\text{get?}(m),} \\
               & & & & & \text{seq} &( & \text{send}(\text{contents}(m), c), \\
               & & & & & & & \text{ready}(b(c))), \\
               & & & & & \text{if}\:( & & \text{set?}(m),\\
               & & & & & & & \text{ready}(b(\text{contents}(m))), \\
               & & & & & & & \text{ready}(b(c)))))
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit hard coding but easiest and enough fast (is it what You need?):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}




\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{cell} =  \text{rec} (&\lambda b.\lambda c.\lambda m.\\
                           &\text{if} (\text{get?}(m), \\
                           &          \quad \text{seq} (\text{send}(\text{contents}(m), c),\\ 
                           & \qquad \quad \text{ready}(b(c))), \\
                           & \quad\text{if}  (\text{set?}(m), \\
                           &\qquad\text{ready}(b(\text{contents}(m))), \\
                           &\qquad\text{ready}(b(c))))) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Looks good. Why does mine fail?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand Your question, You mean why Your code do not produse the same result as mine? or what?

Answer (score 2):

Probabily your code can be more fine if it is used `lambdax` package here on this link, https://ctan.org/pkg/lambdax

To work with this package you should download the `lambdax.sty` and `keyparse.sty` from your TeX distribuition (on MikTeX the answer is yes.)

Reading the explanation there is written *This package provides Lambda expressions.* that it is your objective.

Here there is a small example taken from https://github.com/rogard/lambdax/blob/main/testfiles/lambdax-001.lvt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lambdax}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\START
\box_new:N \l_tmp_box
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmp_box{\LambdaX{(#1)}{x}}
\box_use:N \l_tmp_box
%\END
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```